# Incorporate Weights/Offsets with Nonparametric Models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, random-forest, caret, offset, tweedie-distribution

I am modeling pure premium in R. I have read that pure premiums are usually modeled using a Tweedie distribution (glm). There is generally an offset or weight added to the model, such as an exposure. I am investigating three nonparametric models for pure premiums: glmnet, regression trees, and random forest. My question: how can I incorporate a weight/offset with a nonparametric model? The two package I normally use for modeling in R are caret and tidymodels.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, such an exposure term is intended to model rates rather than count data. For example, from the Poisson regression (one possible model in the Tweedie family) [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#.22Exposure.22_and_offset): `Poisson regression may also be appropriate for rate data, where the rate is a count of events divided by some measure of that unit's exposure (a particular unit of observation)`.

$\log(\operatorname{E}(Y\mid x)) = \log(\text{exposure}) + \theta' x$

The added exposure term in this case is a way to model continuous rate data using a Poisson model which is based on discrete count data and accordingly would not be suited to directly model rate data. Note that you don't estimate a coefficient for the log exposure term and if you subtract that term from both sides you simply recover a regression onto $\log\left(\frac{\operatorname{E}(Y\mid x)}{\text{exposure}}\right)$.

For a regression tree or forest, if you have access to the count data and corresponding exposure data and are looking to model the rate (defined by the count $Y$ divided by exposure), you should be able to directly regress onto the rate values. So define a new target variable by $\frac{Y}{exposure}$ and don't include exposure as a covariate in the tree/forest. If you want to recover the raw count values, you can then predict the rate and multiply by the exposure.